# How to construct a database driven Jquery dropdown menu in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am trying to build a fancy jquery dropdown menu ,while making the menu items dynamic by bringing the values of menu items from database. I am using asp.net and sql server 2005 as my database,Is their any simple article to work this?

Comment: i did see a 'lovely' article that used a t4 template to iterate thro the controllers and build a menu. it took into account [authorize] etc, thus having different varients for unauthorized and authenticated users. regret not having bookmarked it - sorry. you should be able to search based on this description hopefully.

Comment: @jim what kind of help is this? Go and search!

Comment: I wish you are using ASP.NET MVC, this could help http://www.ienablemuch.com/2011/05/cascading-dropdownlist-using-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: yes, i know, it was shoddy commenting... just wanted to make a note to the fact that this approach was 'out there'. i did do a search and alas couldn't locate it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Create a page method that your jquery ajax can call and get results from. Populate the dropdown on click, just remember to do something to let the user know that the values are coming since the database might not respond instantly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
     url: yoururl,
     data: { yourfunctiondatavariable},
     cache: false,
     type: "POST",
     success: function (data) {
     var markup = "<option value='0'>----Select----</option>";
     for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) 
     {
     debugger
     markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
      }        
      $("#dropdownname").html(markup).show();
    },
   error: function (reponse) {
   alert("error : " + reponse);
   }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide any additional information or explanation about your code?

Comment: I have done code according to my need .Can you tell me your need so that according to that I can help you.